# android animation with no duration (only with set speed)

Tags: android, animation

I have a linearlayout with some images inside (these images are added
   dynamically so the width of layout will change time to time),

i want
   this layout to animate like a marquee from left to right (i **can not
   use textview with marquee** because it does not support rtl ) so i
   have to deal with animation.
 *the width of layout might change* so i
   cant set an static duration for the animation method setDuration ,
   also when i use for example 10000 ms for the duration sometimes it
   moves too fast and sometimes too slow (because of the width change)

**ok now the question:**
Is there some custom method for example setSpeed for animation class?
how can i achieve this goal? i want this layout to animate with same speed for any size.

Comment: `animation with no duration` which turns into **no animation** at all.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein it has duration but its value is dynamic ( scroll speed of 25 images must be the same as 4 images but with a fixed duration it will not be with same speed)

Comment: yes, use this: v = s / t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can not set a speed to animate a view directly, but you can manipulate it to achieve what you want:**

You can set a LinearInterpolator to your animation to let it have the same regular speed along the whole animation, and implement a listener to do what you want in onAnimationEnd, **and here comes the tricky part:**

**The rule of speed is: `Speed = Distance / Time`**

*Lets apply that in code logically. We will consider that the distance is the total width of the images (or your parent view which is a linear layout). Then multiply that width by 1000 to let the duration be in milliseconds, then divide the result with anything you want to determine your speed. Now your animation speed should be the same regardless of the total width of the images.*

*Similarly, you can multiply the total width of your images by a constant number like 10. It will be the same ratio.*

**Here is how it is done in code:**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
int layoutWidth = linearLayout.getWidth();
int animationSpeed = (layoutWidth * 1000) / 100;

linearLayout.animate().translationX(layoutWidth).setDuration(animationSpeed).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

If you want to make your animation **infinite**, you can do something like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
int layoutWidth = linearLayout.getWidth();
int animationSpeed = (layoutWidth * 1000) / 100;

final TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, layoutWidth, 0, 0);
translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
translateAnimation.setDuration(animationSpeed);
translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        linearLayout.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
linearLayout.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Comment: that static 10000 ms is the problem;the number of images might defer because it gets data from web server , sometimes there is few images and sometimes much more;duration makes 4-image layout to go slow and 25-image layout very fast.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand you now. How about animating each ImageView separately?

Comment: good idea ,but the width of each image is not the same either.i can only work with sum of all width.

Comment: @farshadf Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Before going to open my Android Studio, a quick question, Is there a reason why your layout has to change its size while adding images? You can use HorizontalScrollView outside your layout to keep the images scrolling without changing the layout size and use scrollTo() or smoothScrollTo() to scroll your dynamic images. or use Object animation to scroll a static view where you add your images to inside layout.

**Update 1:**

You need to calculate your initial duration per unit movement of the layout during animation, then that duration/unit can be used for altering animation duration whenever you add a new image to the layout.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll_test);
    final LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollImages);
    durationperunit = duration/ll.getLayoutParams().width;  // duration per move. and this speed has to be maintained while adding images
    duration= speedperunit* ll.getLayoutParams().width;
    ll.animate().setDuration(duration);
    ll.animate().xBy(ll.getWidth()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Rect rect = getDisplaySize();
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollImages);
            if (ll.getX()+ll.getWidth() <= rect.width()) {
                direction = 0;
            }
            if (ll.getX() + ll.getWidth() >= rect.width()) {
                direction = 1;
            }
            if (direction == 0) ll.animate().xBy(ll.getWidth());
            else ll.animate().xBy(-ll.getWidth());

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat (Animator animation){

        }
        @Override
        public  void onAnimationStart (Animator animation){

        }
    });
}
```

Now, you know the time it takes to make a single movement of the layout in "duration". Use it to update animation's setDuration() whenever layout width changes. Note that, when layout width increase, animation duration has to increase. So while adding images, (your layout width also increase) the code has to be something like below, along with the earlier calculated "duration per movement" value.

```
/*within adding image function after layout width change*/
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollImages);
// Now calculate new duration for new width of the layout. Assuming layout width changed already.
duration= durationperunit* ll.getLayoutParams().width;
// Set the newly calculated duration
ll.animate().setDuration(duration);
```

Comment: i can not use HorizontalScrollView  because i am using negative values for left and right (it is exactly like a html marquee ;it moves from outside of screen from left and then moves out to the right and also its is automatic)

Comment: @farshad f, ok. Updated the answer with some codes and suggestions. Please check if it address the problem.